# jQuery Validation Plugin: Unable to get property 'setdefaults' of undefined or null reference IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validate

I have a basic form with input fields that uses client-side validation from jQuery Validation Plugin (http://jqueryvalidation.org/).  The form works fine on our Production site, but for some reason, when I plug it into an Optimizely test, I received the following error in all of IE (FF, Chrome, and Safari are fine):

```
Unable to get property 'setDefaults' of undefined or null reference
```

My js script is below...

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
   debug: false //If true, the form is not submitted and certain errors are     displayed on the console 
});
jQuery("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();  
  },
  rules: {
          //script for rules
  },
  messages: {
          //script for messages
  }
});

jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myForm").validate();

});
```

Is anyone able to see if there's something wrong with my syntax or point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Optimizely uses jQuery version 1.6.4. Make sure that you have not overridden your JQuery settings in Optimizely and use a version of JQuery lower than 1.6.4 or any versions other than what your plugin is tested to only work with.

https://help.optimizely.com/hc/en-us/articles/202480860-Project-Settings

Your validation plugin is only tested to work with JQuery versions 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1 and 1.11.1.

Comment: Thank you so mcuh for your help/advice!  I checked the jQuery version and 1.10.2 was being loaded.  Commenting out "debug: false" seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Is anyone able to see if there's something wrong with my syntax

Another issue here is that you're calling the `.validate()` method twice on the same form...

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: false 
});

jQuery("#myForm").validate({  // FIRST CALL
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();  
    },
    rules: {
        // script for rules
    },
    messages: {
       // script for messages
    }
});

jQuery().ready(function() {
    jQuery("#myForm").validate();  // SECOND CALL IS IGNORED
});
```

The `.validate()` method is only used for *initializing* the plugin on your form and any subsequent calls are always ignored.  So the first `.validate()` method in your code is evaluated by the plugin and the `.validate()` method within your `.ready()` handler is ignored by the plugin.

You can simply put everything inside the DOM ready handler...

```
jQuery().ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: false
    });

    jQuery("#myForm").validate({ // FIRST & ONLY CALL
        // your rules & options
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have referred the `Jquery.datetimepicker.js` in the file loaded.
Maybe you missed the reference.